# What is equivalent for curl --noproxy '*' in rieman.config for defining influxdb-creds

Tags: clojure, influxdb, riemann

I'm forwarding riemann events by code below in `riemann.config`:

```
(def influxdb-creds {
     :version :0.9
     :host "127.0.0.1"
     :port 8086
     :db "riemann"
     ; :username "riemann"
     ; :password "riemann_password"
})

(def influxBatchSender
    (batch 100 1/10
     (async-queue! :agg {:queue-size 1000
                         :core-pool-size 1
                         :max-pool-size 4
                         :keep-alive-time 60000}
                   (influxdb influxdb-creds))))
```

In my environment I need to use `curl --noproxy '*'` to access influxdb, how I can code it in my `riemann.config`?

Answer (score 0):

http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables responsible for this.
Make sure there are no http_proxy and https_proxy variables in your environment.